# I am using NSSortDescriptor with key. When i sort the array it will crashes

Tags: ios

```
 Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<__NSCFConstantString 0xa2f4> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key name.'


agesArray=[NSMutableArray array];
sortDescriptor *a=[[sortDescriptor alloc]init];
a.name=@"SAS";
a.lastname=@"kumar";
[agesArray addObject:a.name];
sortDescriptor *a1=[[sortDescriptor alloc]init];
a1.name=@"DAMAN";
[agesArray addObject:a1.name];

sortDescriptor *a11=[[sortDescriptor alloc]init];
a11.name=@"AKSHAY";
[agesArray addObject:a11.name];
 NSSortDescriptor *sortDesc = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES selector:@selector(compare:)];
[agesArray sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDesc]];
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15841885/ios-terminating-app-due-to-uncaught-exception-nsunknownkeyexception

Answer (score 2):

Your `agesArray` contains `NSString` objects.

```
[agesArray addObject:a.name];   //see you are adding string here
```

`NSString` class does not contain a property called `name`. So it is crashing.

Probably you may want to do something like
`[agesArray addObject:a]`;

***Side note*** : Give meaningful name to objects/Methods or whatever. Objective C demand it. Don`t use a,a1,a11

Comment: i have to sort according to the names. If  had added [agesArray addObject:a]then i will get in agesArray <__NSArrayM 0xa464240>(
<sortDescriptor: 0xa44cb40>,
<sortDescriptor: 0xa450090>,
<sortDescriptor: 0xa455610>
).. Then how i will sort out according to name,

Comment: Yes. That is the expected result. That method is used to sort an array objects based on its properties. Whats wrong in it? instead of log array, iterate the array and try to print the name property. Objects are in sorted order right??

Comment: i want to set property name  in initWithKey: in sort descriptor..If i write @"name" it crashes because  string property is not found. How i will assign string in initwithKey  in sort descriptor.

Comment: @Akshay You are supposed to have an array of Objects and not an array of properties. Once you have the array you can apply nssortdescriptor based on one of the ** property of the object **. [ in your case the property is name ].